# Remove \n from dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My dictionary looks like below:

```
'{\n  "bindings": [\n    {\n      "members": [\n        "user:rohithmn3@gmail.com"\n      ],\n      "role": "roles/browser"\n    },\n    {\n      "members": [\n        "serviceAccount:admin-user@linuxacademy-3.iam.gserviceaccount.com",\n        "user:rohithmn03@gmail.com"\n      ],\n      "role": "roles/owner"\n    },\n    {\n      "members": [\n        "user:rohithmn3@gmail.com"\n      ],\n      "role": "roles/viewer"\n    }\n  ],\n  "etag": "BwVvsH-HhI0=",\n  "version": 1\n}\n'
```

I need to remove `\n` from it;
But `strip()` is not working on it.

Do we have any other way top remove it..!?

Regards,
Rohith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a JSON string there, you should probably use the `json` module:

```
import json
my_dict = json.loads('{\n  "bindings": [\n    {\n      "members": [\n        "user:rohithmn3@gmail.com"\n      ],\n      "role": "roles/browser"\n    },\n    {\n      "members": [\n        "serviceAccount:admin-user@linuxacademy-3.iam.gserviceaccount.com",\n        "user:rohithmn03@gmail.com"\n      ],\n      "role": "roles/owner"\n    },\n    {\n      "members": [\n        "user:rohithmn3@gmail.com"\n      ],\n      "role": "roles/viewer"\n    }\n  ],\n  "etag": "BwVvsH-HhI0=",\n  "version": 1\n}\n')
```

then you have it as an actual dictionary and can do with as you please.  If you want to print it without newlines you could:

```
print(my_dict)
```

or you could use it as a dict, depending on what you were really trying to accomplish with removing the newlines.

If you really have that string and just want to get rid of the newlines in it you can use `.replace` though:

```
'{\n  "bindings": [\n    {\n      "members": [\n        "user:rohithmn3@gmail.com"\n      ],\n      "role": "roles/browser"\n    },\n    {\n      "members": [\n        "serviceAccount:admin-user@linuxacademy-3.iam.gserviceaccount.com",\n        "user:rohithmn03@gmail.com"\n      ],\n      "role": "roles/owner"\n    },\n    {\n      "members": [\n        "user:rohithmn3@gmail.com"\n      ],\n      "role": "roles/viewer"\n    }\n  ],\n  "etag": "BwVvsH-HhI0=",\n  "version": 1\n}\n'.replace('\n', '')
```